# Error 2427 "You entered an expression that has no value." in Access form (VBA)

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am using Access VBA, and I have two forms (form1 and form2), in form 1 I have a listbox control (form1.modifiable49). I choose a list item and with a button control click I open the second form (form2),

In the second form I have some table columns, and I have a textbox where I store my variable,  I would like to open form2 with the element that equals  the value of modifiable49

I have:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.Texte = [Forms]![Form1]![Modifiable49]
    Me.Filter = "[id_parcelle]=" & Texte
    Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

but when I choose the value in the listbox and I excute I get error 2427:

> You entered an expression that has no value.
>
> The expression may refer to an object that has no value, such as a form, a report, or a label control.

Comment: You do not mention which line gets the error. Also, is the listbox entry numeric or alpha? If alphanumeric, then your filter needs to be like: Me.Filter = "[id_parcelle]='" & Me.Texte & "'", However, the biggest issue is your reference to the listbox -- it needs to reference a specific entry within the listbox: i.e. [Forms]![Form1]![Modifiable49].ItemsSelected(0). A simpler method would be to pass the value in the form open event when you click the button..

Comment: i have the error in   this line 
Me.Filter = "[id_parcelle]=" & Texte

Comment: You need more quotes. Filter is a string.

Comment: i have the error in   this line 
Me.Filter = "[id_parcelle]=" & Texte
and my textbox contains the value ( i verified buy a messagebox and i have a value ) 
the listbox entry is numeric

Comment: What/where is 'Texte'? I don't believe 'Texte' contains what you think it does.  As a test, add the following line of code immediately before setting the filter, then paste the result back into this thread.
Debug.Print "My Text: >" & Texte & "<  ListBox: >" & [Forms]![Form1]![Modifiable49] & "<"

Answer (score 0):

This will not fail and will list the value of Texte for you to investigate:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me!Texte.Value = [Forms]![Form1]![Modifiable49].Value
    Debug.Print "Texte:", Me!Texte.Value
    Me.Filter = "[id_parcelle]=" & Me!Texte.Value & ""
    ' or, if Texte is a string:
    ' Me.Filter = "[id_parcelle]='" & Me!Texte.Value & "'"
    Me.FilterOn = Not IsNull(Me!Texte.Value) 
End Sub
```

Comment: it's ok , it works the problem was in the relations between my tables , my code is correct.

Comment: OK. Enjoy the weekend.